# requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, version solving failed. (Flutter and Dart)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, sdk

I keep getting this error when I try to run a flutter app:

```
The current Dart SDK version is 2.10.0.                                 
                                                                        
Because flutter_app depends on path >=1.8.0-nullsafety.3 which requires SDK version >=2.12.0-0 <3.0.0, version solving failed.
```

Here is some info on the Flutter and Dart SDK versions I am running:

```
Flutter 1.22.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision d408d302e2 (1 year, 8 months ago) • 2020-09-29 11:49:17 -0700
Engine • revision 5babba6c4d
Tools • Dart 2.10.0
```

Based on the error message, I tried using Flutter SDK 2.0.0 since that comes with Dart 2.12.0. However, I then get this error instead:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_app... 19.7s



Building without sound null safety
For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety




FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForDevRelease'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:devReleaseRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not resolve androidx.core:core-ktx:+.
Required by:
project :app > project :audioplayers
> Failed to list versions for androidx.core:core-ktx.
> Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/androidx/core/core-ktx/maven-metadata.xml.
> Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/androidx/core/core-ktx/maven-metadata.xml'.
> Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/androidx/core/core-ktx/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 57s
```

In a nutshell, it seems that Flutter 1.22.X is compatible with my project but the Dart SDK that comes with it (2.10.0) is not. But if I upgrade my Flutter SDK to one that contains a compatible Dart SDK, then my Flutter SDK is no longer compatible! Either way I run into issues. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: It seems like you have wrong SDK specified in your `pubspec.yaml` file. By the way, I'd recommend to upgrade your Flutter SDK - 3.0.0 is currently stable

Comment: @Wiktor This is what I have specified in my `pubspec.yaml` file: 

```environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

What should I change it to?

Answer (score 0):

```
You need flutter sdk 1.22.0 to 1.22.6 work for you.
```

[image]

Not every time latest sdk use some project made old version.

Happy Fultter.....

Comment: I'm currently already running Flutter 1.22.0 and I've tried 1.22.6 as well but neither of those work